# React navigation TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to implement react-navigation into my app, but as soon as i launch a simple example app from react-navigation website (link: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/basic-app) it fails with this error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'arr[typeof Symbol === 'function' ? Symbol.iterator : '@@iterator']()')

This error is located at:
    in SafeView (at withOrientation.js:50)
    in withOrientation (at Header.js:315)
    in Header (at withOrientation.js:50)
    in withOrientation (at CardStack.js:170)
    in RCTView (at View.js:113)
    in View (at CardStack.js:397)
    in RCTView (at View.js:113)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:134)
    in AnimatedComponent (at Card.js:26)
    in Card (at PointerEventsContainer.js:55)
    in Container (at CardStack.js:440)
    in RCTView (at View.js:113)
    in View (at CardStack.js:370)
    in RCTView (at View.js:113)
    in View (at CardStack.js:369)
    in CardStack (at CardStackTransitioner.js:103)
    in RCTView (at View.js:113)
    in View (at Transitioner.js:187)
    in Transitioner (at CardStackTransitioner.js:55)
    in CardStackTransitioner (at StackNavigator.js:48)
    in Unknown (at createNavigator.js:48)
    in Navigator (at createNavigationContainer.js:205)
    in NavigationContainer (at renderApplication.js:35)
    in RCTView (at View.js:113)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:102)
    in RCTView (at View.js:113)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:126)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:34)
sliceIterator

<unknown>

<unknown>
    SafeAreaView.js:190:31
_getSafeAreaStyle
    SafeAreaView.js:164:38
render
    SafeAreaView.js:95:26
proxiedMethod
    createPrototypeProxy.js:44:35
finishClassComponent
    ReactNativeFiber-dev.js:1721:102
updateClassComponent
    ReactNativeFiber-dev.js:1713:33
beginWork
    ReactNativeFiber-dev.js:1833:44
performUnitOfWork
    ReactNativeFiber-dev.js:2569:33
workLoop
    ReactNativeFiber-dev.js:2595:141
_invokeGuardedCallback
    ReactNativeFiber-dev.js:75:23
invokeGuardedCallback
    ReactNativeFiber-dev.js:49:40
performWork
    ReactNativeFiber-dev.js:2634:41
scheduleUpdateImpl
    ReactNativeFiber-dev.js:2768:101
scheduleUpdate
    ReactNativeFiber-dev.js:2751:38
scheduleTopLevelUpdate
    ReactNativeFiber-dev.js:3048:91
updateContainer
    ReactNativeFiber-dev.js:3059:39
render
    ReactNativeFiber-dev.js:4483:53
renderApplication
    renderApplication.js:34:4
run
    AppRegistry.js:117:10
runApplication
    AppRegistry.js:191:26
__callFunction
    MessageQueue.js:306:47
<unknown>
    MessageQueue.js:108:26
__guard
    MessageQueue.js:269:6
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
    MessageQueue.js:107:17
```

This is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Welcome',
  };
  render() {
    return <Text>Hello, Navigation!</Text>;
  }
}

export const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('navigation', () => SimpleApp);
```

I looked at other queries but it seems that everyone is getting a problem with navigate function, I don't even call navigate I just want to start the app with navigation.
Can you please help me? Thank you in advance :)

SOLVED!!! if you're having the same problem look at this github post https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/2853

Comment: Is this code from your index.js file or App.js file? Can you add the code from the other one please

Comment: I put it all into index.js file since it wasn't working in App.js. I don't have anything in App.js currently neither am I importing it into index.js

Comment: I found out that TabNavigator works perfectly well

Comment: What was the project name when you run react-native init command?

Comment: It was navigation and I typed it in registerComponent correctly I think

Comment: It might be related to that stacknavigator needs at least 2 screens. Can you try to add a second screen to the navigator please

Comment: Added a second screen, still nothing.

Comment: Really interesting. I can't see anything wrong then. Most interesting part is that TabNavigator working ans Stack isn't.

Comment: [2853](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/2853) [2862](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/2862)